# Change element class name when hovering parent mootools

Tags: mootools

In this jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/vnKdu/7/
I made 3 boxes with info container, currently the effect works fine when you hover the info container and his height changes from 35px to 150px  but I need to do same effect when hovering the parent not the actual element. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vnKdu/9/

You should have set mouse events to parent element and morph child, just it.

Comment: this is what i was missing var div = el.getFirst();.  awesome . thank you!